# Can you pickle methods python method objects using any pickle module?

Tags: python, pickle

I've got a long-running script, and the operations that it performs can be broken down into independent, but order-sensitive function calls. In addition, the pattern here is a bread-first walk over a graph, and restarting a depth after a crash is not a happy option.

So then, my idea is as follows: as the script runs, maintain a list of function-argument pairs. This list corresponds to the open list of a depth-first search of the graph. The data is readily accessible, so I don't need to be concerned about losing it.

In the (probably unavoidable) event of a crash due to network conditions or an error, the list of function argument pairs is enough to resume the operation.

So then, can I store the functions? My intuition says no, but I'd like some advice before I judge either way.

Comment: Have you tried it? (Surprise ending: yes, you can.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pickle plain functions. Python stores the name and module and uses that to reload it. If you want to do the same with methods and such that's a little bit trickier. It can be done by breaking such objects down into component parts and pickling those.

Comment: This suffices. I suppose I should have said functions rather than methods. How does this work with decorated methods and such, where the name alone doesn't necessarily identify the function?

Comment: @Alex, that probably breaks. Pickle has lots of options for customization, so you can probably get around that.

Answer (score 0):

If the arguments are all that matters, why not store the arguments? Just store it as a straight tuple.

Comment: I would do this, but the only issue is that I'm calling more than one function, so I need to pickle the function itself. I figured I can pickle the function name itself, and then use `module.getattr` to fetch it.